# how to make unclickable Headings in Modern SharePoint Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience

Is there any way I can make the left navigation links heading as inactive? currently if i keep heading as empty it is redirecting to welcome page

[image]

Comment: Can you attach any screenshot or anything of how you have added navigation link? Are you using Team site??

Comment: i have activated publising feature to work on structured navigation if i keep it blank as well it is clickable and navigate to welcome page

Comment: it occuring only when i am on modern page in classic view link are noclickable

Comment: this issue resolved thank you for the assistance i again created links its working

Comment: Welcome, you can answer your own question by adding more details and steps how you resolved your issue.